# handling pagination , clicking on element parent

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

im trying to handle pagination in my page , the pagination links are like this

```
<a href="nextpage.php"> <img src="pic.jpg" id="next"></a>
```

this is my code to click on this link

```
 while (has_next_page)
{
      // do some data scraping 

            if ( await page.$("img#next"))
            {

                console.log('clicking on next page');
                await  page.click('#next');

                await Promise.all([
                    page.waitForNavigation() ,
                    page.waitForSelector('#rowTbl'),
                ]).catch(function(){
                    throw new Error(tab_id + ' error waitning for rowTbl');
                })

            }
            else
                has_next_page = false ;
}
```

for some reason this doesn't work , and even after clicking it doesn't navigate to the next page .. .so i thought maybe i have to click on `a` tab instead of `img`  ... so here is my question , how can i click on `img#next` parent  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `.evaluate()` instead to trigger a click event on an element that you can't use a selector for.

```
await page.evaluate(() => { document.querySelector("#next").parentNode.click(); });
```

Comment: thanx , that did it